# PHP class not found in Laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I'm having an issue within a Laravel controller, I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting. Basically 2 separate methods are calling the same external class; the `process` method works, however when calling `process3d` I run into the error `class 'App\Services\PaymentGateway\Gateway\RequestGatewayEntryPointList' not found.`

DebugController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Services\PaymentGateway\Gateway\RequestGatewayEntryPointList;
...
public function process(Request $request) {
   ...
   $rgeplRequestGatewayEntryPointList = new RequestGatewayEntryPointList;
   ...
}

public function process3d(Request $request) {
   ...
   $rgeplRequestGatewayEntryPointList = new RequestGatewayEntryPointList;
   ...
}
```

PaymentSystem.php

```
namespace App\Services\PaymentGateway\Gateway;
...
class RequestGatewayEntryPointList {
   ...
}
```

I've omitted irrelevant code to keep the question brief, but I'm of course happy to provide more details if it will help.

What's going on?

Comment: And you are using both functions inside the same controller, `DebugController.php`?

Comment: Yes, just to clarify- I was. However in the process method, I was bringing in the PaymentSystem.php file which I had forgotton to bring in for the process3d method. This was the issue.

Comment: Hmm, does that mean you are calling "require_once" inside each function? If so, that may work, but its definitely not the best way to do it, the file should be autoloaded via composer and included once in the controller via a `use` statement like  `RequestGatewayEntryPointList`

Answer (score 1):

Found it 5 minutes after posting to stackoverflow... oops.

process3d was missing require_once **DIR**.'/../../Services/PaymentGateway/Gateway/PaymentSystem.php';

Adding this solved the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I would expect such a class to be autoloaded, not manually required. Are you certain that `use Services/PaymentGateway/Gateway/PaymentSystem.php`  or similar is not what you're after? (note that the path may be incorrect, youd need to check where it is exactly)

Comment: why would you be manually 'requiring' files when you have composer as the autoloader? just curious

Comment: While requiring manually solved the issue, it does feel like a workaround rather than a clean fix. However I am not sure what the issue is, or how to solve it otherwise.

2 points.

1. ```App/Services/PaymentGateway/Gateway/PaymentSystem.php``` is NOT a class, it is a php file containing many classes.
2 This is in the context of a Laravel project, which I believe requires PSR-4 compliance. My understanding is that, seeing as PaymentSystem.php is not a class, I can't write ```use App/Services/PaymentGateway/Gateway/PaymentSystem``` in my controller and access the classes within..?